# Correct bridging for ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a category class for NSString.

```
@implementation NSString (URLEncode)

- (NSString *)URLEncodedString
{
    __autoreleasing NSString *encodedString;

    NSString *originalString = (NSString *)self;    
    encodedString = (__bridge_transfer NSString * )
            CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                (__bridge CFStringRef)originalString,
                                NULL,
                                (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return encodedString;
}
```

Am I using the correct bridge transfers for ARC and the new LLVM?

The original code:

```
- (NSString *)URLEncodedString
    NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                (CFStringRef)self,
                                NULL,
                                (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [encodedString autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I think it's fine to talk about ARC and the contents of [Automatic Reference Counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) here.

`__autoreleasing` is not meant to be used like that. It's used for passing indirect object references (NSError**, etc). See [4.3.4 Passing to an out parameter by writeback](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.restrictions.pass_by_writeback).

According to [3.2.4 Bridged casts](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts), the `__bridge_transfer` is correct as the `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` function returns a retained object (it has "create" in its name). You want ARC to take ownership of the returned object and insert a release (or autorelease in this case) to balance this out.

The `__bridge` cast for `originalstring` is correct too, you don't want ARC to do anything special about it.

Comment: Thank-you - this helped immensely. I just wanted to make sure that my understanding of the docs were correctly being applied.

Comment: I might add that using the `CFBridgingRelease()` macro makes transfer and consumption of CFType Objects way easier to read - at least in my eyes. e.g. `NSData *imageData = CFBridgingRelease(ABPersonCopyImageData(person))`

Answer (score 28):

This is a correct, not leaking version.
As you say in the comments: `__bridge_transfer` transfer the ownership to `NSObject` `(NSString)` and assume that the object is retained by `CF Framework` (the method `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` return a `retained` object so this is what we need)
than on the self object we don't want to perform any memory management. Hope it helps
Fra

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
           (__bridge CFStringRef)self,
           NULL,
           (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
           CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString *) urlEncoded
{
    CFStringRef encodedCfStringRef = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)self,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();@+$,%#[]% ",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
    NSString *endcodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(encodedCfStringRef);
    return endcodedString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No `__autoreleasing` necessary. The correct ARC syntax is simply:

```
- (NSString *)URLEncodedString
{
    return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                     NULL,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```