# iOS URL library?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String won't url encode in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187316/string-wont-url-encode-in-ios)

I am using ASIHttpRequest to send http request to my server. In Jquery I can construct a dictionary and just send the dictionary to jquery's ajax method, the Jquery will do the url encode things.

It looks like ASIHttp lacks of such API? Which API I can use to encode a dictionary(or other simple method) to a url encoded string?

Comment: http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc;
```

Example:

```
NSString* string = @"Hello, World";
NSString* encodedString = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```