# Crashing on unrecognized selector sent with SimplePost request after it works successfully.

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, analyzer

I've been using the SimplePost classes for several weeks and haven't had any problems.  Now I'm crashing after a Request returns proper data in a Connection.  I haven't (knowingly) touched the SimplePost class files.  But when I run the analyzer, it now (never did before) points out the following method:

```
+ (NSMutableURLRequest *) urlencodedRequestWithURL:(NSURL *)url andDataDictionary:(NSDictionary *) dictionary {
   //  Create POST request
   NSMutableURLRequest *urlencodedPostRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [urlencodedPostRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   //  Add HTTP header info
   [urlencodedPostRequest addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
   //  Add POST body
   NSMutableData *POSTBody = [NSMutableData data];
   //  Add k/v to the body
   NSArray *keyArray = [dictionary allKeys];
   for( int i = 0; i < [keyArray count]; ++i ) {
       // Core Foundation function used to transform @ ==> %40 , etc
       NSString *escapedString = (__bridge NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)([dictionary objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:i]]),NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
       [POSTBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", [keyArray objectAtIndex:i], escapedString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       if( i < ([keyArray count] - 1) ) {
            [POSTBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       }
   }
   [urlencodedPostRequest setHTTPBody:POSTBody];
   return urlencodedPostRequest;
}
```

And running the Analyzer shows me:

[image: bug prt1]
the lines continue as:
 [image: bug prt2]

I'm having a hard time understanding what's happening.  Can anyone help, please?  Thanks!

Comment: I've presented this same crashing incident with different symptoms [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726976/crashing-after-view-controller-url-request-and-connection-finish-correctly).  I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `__bridge_transfer` for `escapedString`?

```
   NSString *escapedString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)([dictionary objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:i]]),NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

cf. [Correct bridging for ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822473/correct-bridging-for-arc)

Comment: Have you tried by commenting the `PostBody appendData` lines and `NSLog` the `escapedString`?

Comment: Good suggestion. Let me see a lot. But I didn't see anything wrong there.