# Crashing after view controller URL request and connection finish correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, connection, request, unrecognized-selector

My app goes to a viewcontroller, makes two automatic server requests, makes the connection, retrieves the data and correctly displays it, and is done.  The user clicks a "likes" button and two more server requests are made - successfully.  Displays are correct.  Should be done.  Then it crashes, with the error:

```
[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I'm using the very handy SimplePost class (by Nicolas Goles).  Here are my requests, which are both called in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void) setScore {
    Profile *newPf = [[Profile alloc] initID:thisUser profil:@"na" scor:score];
    NSMutableURLRequest *reqPost = [SimplePost urlencodedRequestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kMyProfileURL] andDataDictionary:[newPf toDictPf]];
    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:reqPost delegate:self];
}
- (void) saveHist {
    History *newH = [[History alloc] initHistID:thisUser hQid:thisQstn hPts:score hLiked:NO];
    NSMutableURLRequest *reqHpost = [SimplePost urlencodedRequestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kMyHistURL] andDataDictionary:[newH toDictH]];
    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:reqHpost delegate:self];
}
```

The only "new" thing with my custom classes (Profile and History) is the BOOL for hLiked, but it's "working" - the database is updating correctly.
Then, the user can click a "Likes" button (+ or -).  Here are the other requests:

```
- (IBAction)likeClick:(id)sender {
    double stepperValue = _likeStepper.value;
    _likesLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", stepperValue];
    [self updateLikes];
    [self updateHist];
}
- (void) updateLikes {
    //  update the question with the new "liked" score
    NSInteger likesN = [_likesLbl.text integerValue];
    Questn *qInfo = [[Questn alloc] initQwID:thisQstn askID:0 wCat:@"na" wSit:@"na" wAns1:@"na" wPts1:0 wAns2:@"na" wPts2:0 wAns3:@"na" wPts3:0 wAns4:@"na" wPts4:0 wJust:@"na" wLikes:likesN ];
    NSMutableURLRequest *reqPost = [SimplePost urlencodedRequestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kLikesURL] andDataDictionary:[qInfo toDictQ]];
    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:reqPost delegate:self];
}
- (void) updateHist {
    History *newH = [[History alloc] initHistID:thisUser hQid:thisQstn hPts:98989 hLiked:YES];
    NSMutableURLRequest *reqHpost = [SimplePost urlencodedRequestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kHistURL] andDataDictionary:[newH toDictH]];
    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:reqHpost delegate:self];
}
```

Messy, right?  Here's my connection code:

```
//  connection to URL finished with Plist-formatted user data array returned from PHP
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSDictionary *array = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:0 errorDescription:nil];
    BOOL keyLikeExists = [array objectForKey:@"likes"] != nil;
    if( keyLikeExists ) {
        _likesLbl.text = [array objectForKey:@"likes"];
    }
}
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection did fail." );
}
```

It all does a good job, and then a couple of seconds later it crashes with that "unrecognized selector" error mentioned above, like there's still some URL activity happening.  There shouldn't be.

Anybody seen this kind of thing before?  Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I hope I'm not breaking StackOverflow protocol, but this crash is the same one as I presented in question #13726202[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726202/crashing-on-unrecognized-selector-sent-with-simplepost-request-after-it-works-su), but with totally different symptoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code there's a call to the method `isEqualToString:`.  The thing that's being sent that message is a `NSNumber` object rather than a string.  Either there's a logic problem concerning the object type or there's a memory problem where a string was over-released and its memory is being re-used to hold a number.

Without seeing the context for the call, it's hard to guess.

If you break on the exception, the stack trace should tell you where in the code it's failing.

Comment: Now I have to show my debugging ignorance.  I set the symbolic break for NSInvalidArgumentException, then ran the app.  Crashed as expected. Xcode shows me the main.m with a green pointer at @autoreleasepool {   return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));  }  What's that mean?

Comment: Oh, isEqualToString.  Yeah, I've been searching for one of those near the crash point which could lead to problems.  Can't find anything unusual, logic-related.  Over-releasing possible with ARC?

Comment: Mostly it means that Xcode is annoying some times.  :)  Use the Breakpoint Navigator (tab at top of left-side view) and add a breakpoint for all Objective-C exceptions.

Comment: (What it **actually** means is that an exception was thrown and, since it was never caught, Xcode reports that the first line of the program was responsible...which I guess is technically true but of no help whatsoever.)

Comment: Yay! Thanks so much, Phillip.  You found my bug AND taught me how to debug better.  Yes, _likesLbl.text = [array objectForKey:@"likes"]; is putting an INT in a STRING.  I need a break.